# Add class to correct option

Tags: reactjs

I am doing quiz app. I add class active if clicked element is correct. But it adds active class to all array which are correct. I need to add active class to correct option from one question array, not to 2 question arrays.
https://codepen.io/rapprogtrain/pen/Jjjjyev

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = 
      {
      questions: [{title: "Question-1", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:2}, {title: "Question-2", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:0}], 
   // ...
    }
    
    // ...
  }
  
  checkAnswer(q, i) {
    if (q.correct === i && !q.answered) {
      q.answered = true;
      this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1, activeItem: q.correct});
    }
     
  }
            
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
          this.state.questions.map((q, i) => (
            // ...
                {q.answers.map((answer, j) => 
           <button className={this.state.activeItem === j ? 'active' : ''}
             key={j} onClick={ () => {
                  this.checkAnswer(q, j);
                     }}>{answer}</button>
                 )}
            // ...
          ))
        }
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to your question.

You need to check if the question is already answered and the current button is the correct answer.

```
   className={q.answered && j === q.correct ? 'active' : ''}
```

And also you need to save questions state value when `answered` is updated to `true`.

```
// These codes are in my codepen
  checkAnswer(i, j) {
    const { questions, score } = this.state;
    if (questions[i].correct === j && !questions[i].answered) {
      questions[i].answered = true;
      this.setState(
        {
          score: score + 1,
          questions,
        });
    }
  }
```

Here is the full code of [codepen](https://codepen.io/minion/pen/VwwwBGb?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that we should know the current question/active question. For that, here we passed current question index to the `checkAnswer` function.

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sq6ajy9h/)

```
checkAnswer(q, i, queIndex) {
  this.setState({ queIndex: queIndex });
  if (q.correct === i && !q.answered) {
    q.answered = true;
    this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1, activeItem: q.correct});
  }
}


....


 <button className={this.state.queIndex == i && this.state.activeItem === j ? 'active' : ''}
         key={j} onClick={ () => {
              this.checkAnswer(q, j, i); // Passing i(Question index) to function
                 }}>{answer}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have state to keep track of the question like you have for the selected answer, 
[Here](https://codepen.io/ibtsamgujjar/pen/YzzzjjQ?editors=0010)

```
checkAnswer(q, i, j) {
if (q.correct === i && !q.answered) {
  q.answered = true;
  q.active = 1

  const questions = this.state.questions
  questions[j] = q;
  console.log(questions)
  this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1, activeItem: q.correct, 
  activeQuestion: j, questions});
}

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but it does not remain, how to make so that if you clicked at first question row active remains and in second row the same

Comment: Check the above answer and demo link @rapprogtrainsite

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite i have updated my answer please check